# if($variable!='') clarification

Tags: php

```
if($hOne!='') {
   echo 'yes';
 } else {
   echo 'no';
}
```

SO for a while i have been using the above code to determine id X variable has been set, now this was working ok until working on a wordpress site (i wont go into too much details) but basically initially the varabile has never been touched and works as intended, if you enter a value and then delete that value it seems to think its been set.

a way i got round this is to use the below code, my question is, is there a better way to do this.

Cheers

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/i', $hone)) {
       echo 'yes';
     } else {
       echo 'no';
    }
```

---

**Result** Used the below which works as intended, thank you all:

```
if(isset($hone) and
       !empty($hone)) {
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo '2';
    }
```

Comment: This makes me sad....  isset and empty exist for a reason.

Comment: Have you checked empty() and isset() functions? they could prove useful if you just want to know about variable existence.

Comment: thank you both for this empty it is then

Comment: @DanLee my point is that bad PHP coding practices make me sad.  (I should have made it clearer though that I did not mean it in a negative way towards the question asker.  It was aimed at the state of PHP learning materials and the knowledge of the language in general.)

Comment: @Corbin Thanks for pointing out. I totally agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right. My advice is to go back and read the PHP documentation. Make it a week or two project to get most sections at least glimpsed at.

You want to use isset, or empty.

```
if (isset($hOne)) { }
```

will check if the variable exists,

```
if (empty($hOne)) { }
```

checks if it is set but empty.

To help you learn PHP, I'd recommend sticking this at the top of your app:

```
$test_server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost" || substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,3) == "192"; 

ini_set('display_errors',$test_server);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',$test_server);

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

(Or if you are not working locally, just set $test_server to 1.)

Comment: +1, but it seems easier to just set the values in the php.ini or per virtual host if a server is being used for mixed dev and prod deployments.

Comment: Glad to help. Corbin, I agree, but this works for everyone no matter how it's set up.

Answer (score 1):

`isset` and `empty` functions must be used to determine if variable exists and are non-empty.

But this one:

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/i', $hone)) {
   echo 'yes';
} else {
   echo 'no';
}
```

Checks if variable (string) contains almost one letter (case no matter). 
Actually it's also pretty dumb (it uses `/../i` -- ignore case, and patter `A-Za-z`)

Comment: thank you, it was just something i quickly knocked up, ill use empty

Comment: added what i used, i should read up before i jump in sometimes, thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should not just use `if ($x != '')` to check if a variable is set or not. For example, I could set the variable thus `$x = ''`. You should check if it's set like so: `isset($x)` and check if it's set but empty: `empty($x)`

Comment: I think there's a "not" missing the first sentence?  If not, then there are situations in which that is incorrect.